# Rails API Mode ApplicationController ignores Rails.application.config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I recently converted an existing Rails 6 application to an API-only application following [this guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/api_app.html#changing-an-existing-application) as well as some helpful information from [here](https://pragmaticstudio.com/tutorials/rails-session-cookies-for-api-authentication).

My frontend application uses session cookies to maintain authentication with the server (with a rack-cors setup) and all that works when I manually test it. Since I'm using a session cookie, I added CSRF protection with a cookie in my application controller like this:

```rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::API
  include ActionController::Cookies
  include ActionController::RequestForgeryProtection

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  after_action :set_csrf_cookie

  def set_csrf_cookie
    cookies['X-CSRF-Token'] = form_authenticity_token
  end
```

The problem I'm having is that my rspec tests are all failing with CSRF-related issues. Usually CSRF is disabled in the test environment in rails (as documented [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/guides/source/configuring.md#configuring-action-controller)), however I ran `rails console -e test` the following on both the API app and the old app and got a discrepancy:

Regular rails app:

```rb
Rails.application.config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection
>> false
ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection
>> false
```

API mode app:

```rb
Rails.application.config.action_controller.allow_forgery_protection
>> false
ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection
>> true
```

Sure enough, when I disable CSRF protection completely, the tests start looking better.

Is there anyway to restore this behaviour in a Rails API app?

EDIT: I've also tried the above with a fresh rails app generated by `rails new --api` and I got the same behaviour.

Comment: since you had the same error when created a new app in api mode, i think it'll be useful to see some test code because maybe there is the issue

Comment: I think the best test code is the `rails console -e test` experiment that I did, since I **know** that when `ApplicationController.allow_forgery_protection` is false, the spec passes. In case it is helpful though, [this is one of the specs I'm looking at](https://gitlab.com/hunt-console/console-backend/-/blob/master/spec/requests/authentication_spec.rb#L17).